# press spaceBar from inputRef

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I captured an element with the useRef hook of React. if i console.log(this.inputRef) i get:

```html
<input aria-invalid="false" autocomplete="off" class="MuiInputBase-input-409 MuiInput-input-394" placeholder="Type ItemCode or scan barcode" type="text" value="2">
```

Is there a way to trigg the spacebar keypress on my inputRef?

Comment: May you add the react code you're talking about?

Comment: Could you explain what you try to solve by doing that? There might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Maybe `inputRef.current.focus()` is what you want.  Or if you want to add a `space ( )` you can `inputRef.current.value = ' ';`.